# Capybara (with selenium-webdriver/firefox) doesn't always wait for page to load before looking for content

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Within my site, I have two types of pages, one for each "thing" and the user's homepage.

- When you visit a page for a thing, you can click a link for "Request a Thing", which sends off an ajax call and then removes the link from that page.
- If you then go to your homepage, you'll see an indication that you have requested a "thing" (and the request is now in Stage1).
- Some other stuff happens elsewhere and eventually the request is in Stage2.
- At that point, on your homepage you'll see a link for Stage3, clicking on it changes the state of the request to Stage3. An ajax call changes the link to Stage4 without reloading the page.
- If click on the Stage4 link, the state of the request is now in Stage4 and the link is removed completely.
- If you then reload your homepage, the indication of the request is no longer there at all.

Here's my test for this:

```
describe "Clicking Through Stages" do
  let(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:thing) { FactoryGirl.create(:thing) }

  subject { page }

  before do
    sign_in user1
    visit thing_path(thing.id)
    click_on "Request a Thing"
    wait_for_ajax

    # This is how I mimic the "other stuff" that happens to get it to Stage2.
    user.requests.first.request_states.create(state: 2)

    visit user_path(user1)
    click_on "Stage3"
    click_on "Stage4"
    visit user_path(user1)
  end

  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  it "should remove the request info", js: true do
    should_not have_content "Request for THG123"
  end

  after do
    sign_out
  end
end
```

Note on wait_for_ajax:

- I was finding that some of the times, the test would fail because user.requests.first was nil, I assume this was happening because it was trying to issue the create before the ajax call for 'click on "Request a Thing"' finished (which is where the Request object is initially created), so I inserted the wait_for_ajax call based on what I read at http://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara.

Some times the test passes. When it fails, I get:

```
 Failure/Error: should_not have_content "Request for THG123"
   expected #has_content?("Request for THG123") to return false, got true
```

So I can tell that the "should_not have_content" is running before the final "visit user_path(user1)" has reloaded the page. I've read that this type of call should rely on Capybara's built in waiting mechanism (and I bumped up the default_wait_time to 5) even for a negative condition, but it does not appear to be doing so in this case.

Similar questions about waiting for a second page to load have offered up the kludgy solution of putting a second-page-specific expect(page).to have_content in there, but that won't work when reloading the same page.

Suggestions?